# Stemmer function in R Slow

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis, snowball

I am trying to run stemmer function on a dataset(uploaded through data.table package) in R of around 40000 rows,but its taking forever to run. My code looks like this:

```
data[, Description := map(Description, function(k) stemmer(k))]
```

If manually stop the process, it shows more than 50 warnings as:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYKsE.jpg)

Is there an alternative to run it faster. My computer has 8Gb ram.

Comment: stemmer in general takes long time, did you check the time difference for running say 10 records?

Comment: Yeah running it on 10 rows is faster but what's the alternative, how do I do it for the entire data??

Comment: try running it in batch, stemmer does take lot of time wen you use large dataset. have you tried lapply?

Comment: Yeah using lapply works,much faster.Thank You

Comment: can you please accept my answer if it resolved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lapply`, your function will run faster